# MongoDB: Using collections as variables

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6

This is how I am defining multiple collections. In the second script I'll get the data of the collections, but as you can see this is an if/else-construction with repeating code.
So I want to get a general codeblock with a variable, but how do I have to do that?

**collections.js**

```
import Animals              from './animals/collection.js';
import Cars                 from './cars/collection.js';
// ...

export { Animals, Cars };
```

**script.js**

```
import * as collections     from './collections.js';

if (collection === 'Animals') {
    server.execute((id) => {
        const   testDataset = Animals.findOne({ title: 'Lorem ipsum' }),
                docID       = id || testDataset && testDataset._id ? testDataset._id : undefined;

        if (!docID) return;
        Animals.remove({ _id: docID });
    }, DOC_ID);
}

else if (collection === 'Cars') {
    server.execute((id) => {
        const   testDataset = Cars.findOne({ title: 'Lorem ipsum' }),
                docID       = id || testDataset && testDataset._id ? testDataset._id : undefined;

        if (!docID) return;
        Cars.remove({ _id: docID });
    }, DOC_ID);
}

else if {
    // Many more like this
}
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
server.execute((id) => {
    const   testDataset = collections[collection].findOne({ title: 'Lorem ipsum' }),
            docID       = id || testDataset && testDataset._id ? testDataset._id : undefined;

    if (!docID) return;
    collections[collection].remove({ _id: docID });
}, DOC_ID);
```

And maybe this little code can be simplified a bit?